# FacebookSDK.h not found - Xcode 6.2, Facebook-iOS-SDK 4.0

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, xcode-6.2

I am using Xcode 6.2, Facebook-iOS-SDK 4.0. I used to have working code with Facebook-iOS-SDK 3.20.0.But, now I am getting compile-time error FacebookSDK.h not found. I am using pod to install sdk. Can someone give me any pointers why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK (v 4.0) is no longer one framework named "FacebookSDK", but rather a few different packages with a naming convention of "FBSDKTypeKit", where types are different things like Core and Login. This means the name of the header files have also changed, so that's why your project can no longer find FacebookSDK.h (as it's now FBSDKCoreKit.h).

Comment: where can I find more info on this? Instead of using FacebookSDK, I should use FBSDKCoreKit.h. I didn't find any FB docs for the same.

Comment: is it possible to continue using 3.x version for everything via pod and only for new messenger functionality use FBSDKMessengerShareKit.framework via pkg. I am asking this because although I want to try the new messenger functionality, I don't want to spend time upgrading my existing code to conform to 4.X

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how Pod works given I've never used it, but most package management tools have an option for you to specify which version you wish to use explicitly. A quick google revealed: `This will take the latest version of the library and include that one in your project. If you want a specific version, you specify it behind the pod name.

pod ‘AFNetworking’, ‘~> 1.1.0′` You should be able to use both SDKs side by side, you'll just have to import both to your project.